# How can I get the most recent value from a data stream in a separate Python multiprocessing process?

Tags: python, embedded, python-multiprocessing

I have a process that reads from a sensor and another that reads from the graph. However, the grapher can be slower than the sensor reading, especially when many sensors are added on.

I see two options to pass the information from the sensor to the grapher: pipes and mp.Value. Pipes from what I know should be faster, but I worry about the issue where the grapher starts to delay: if the sensor sample n times as fast as the grapher, then with every grapher time step, we are only progressing 1/n timesteps in the future (e.g. if twice as fast, after 20s the grapher only has displayed 10s). I could see the sensor polling the pipe and removing all values before adding a new value, but that sounds expensive comptutationally. The mp.Value route does require more explicit locking and I believe isn't as fast as the Pipe class, although I don't know for sure.

What would be the best way to approach this multiprocessing to avoid issues here?

Edit for clarification: I don't care if the grapher gets all the information. Using the most recent value is fine, which is why the title says "Pipe only Last Value". The main requirement of the grapher is just to have the plot not get delayed, even if we effectively downsample by throwing away data. The sensor does need to sample faster than the grapher reads though as the data is also being recorded and processed, and we don't want to downsample that information.

Comment: Note that the [multiprocessing] tag does not refer to the Python `multiprocessing` class/package.  Changed tag to reflect that.   How is the [embedded] tag justified in this? Ultimately if you cannot process the data faster than you are producing it, no amount of buffering will help unless the period for which you are gathering data is finite.  You would need to accelerate the processing.  Also if your platform is not real-time capable (and Python is not regardless), you may still have problems.

Comment: Why exactly do you need to plot the graph in real-time? And if that's a requirement then why did you pick Python?

Comment: Python was legacy code, and i'm not trying to process faster than producing. I want the grapher to just sample the most recent values. E.g., if the sensor samples twice as fast than the grapher, I want the grapher to only get the most recent value, so effectively sampling every other. The grapher does not need all the data, but the sensor does need to sample faster to record all the information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the most up-to-date sensor value, you actually need the sensor process to wait until the grapher is ready to send data. There are several ways to do this, but I think actually using *two* unidirectional (`duplex=False`) pipes is the best way to go, because you don't need to involve any extra threads or semaphores. In this setup, the first pipe sends data sensor->grapher as normal but the second is simply signals that the grapher is ready to immediately accept data. It's a little awkward to express in prose so here is pseudo code:

```py
def grapher():
    while True:
        data = pipe_to_grapher.recv()
        graph(data)
        pipe_to_sensor.send(None)  # Can be any value

def sensor():
    while True:
        data = sense()
        if pipe_to_sensor.poll():
            pipe_to_grapher.send(data)  # Freshest possible
            pipe_to_sensor.recv()  # Clear the pipe
        record(data)
```

Note that the sensor can simply pass right on by if [`poll()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.connection.Connection.poll) returns `False`, as it is an indication that the grapher is not ready for data yet. You can also easily extend the system to use special values to communicate something about the state of one process to the other, such as a shutdown command.

(Pre-edit answer follows)

This question appears to be asking about applying [backpressure](https://medium.com/@jayphelps/backpressure-explained-the-flow-of-data-through-software-2350b3e77ce7) to your sensor data flow. It sounds like a [`multiprocessing.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) might be a good solution for your specific case. Internally it uses a pipe, so it will have similar performance characteristics, but it also has specifically the method [`put()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.put) that can be used with a `maxsize` parameter that you can set to a low number like 1, so that the sensor process will wait until the grapher process has retrieved an item before going back to acquire more data.

If the sensor has its own buffer that needs clearing, you can use `put_nowait()` instead and catch the `Full` error as an indication that the grapher won't be able to plot that data and it should be discarded. This saves the overhead of pickling and sending the data, but can lead to very rapidly polling the sensor which may be a source of overhead itself, depending on the device/drivers/api.

Comment: I editted my post to clarify. I don't care if we have to downsample. I just want to always be able to get the most recent value. However, I don't want the sensor to slow down as we want to record each sample, regardless if it isn't show. 

The biggest issue with the grapher is it must always be real time. If someone interacts with the sensor, we need to see the values change in real time (assume raw magnitude for simplication here). Because of that, we always need the most recent. Sorry if I wasn't clear

Comment: `put_nowait` as I describe in my answer will give you the most up to date data possible given your intrinsic latency of plotting. Will edit to clarify.

Comment: Actually queues have to buffer at least one item so I cooked up a third way that I think will actually address your system in my edit.